# Remove newline from string PHP

Tags: html, string, trim

I've been trying for the last hour to remove newlines/returns from a given string, but it just doesn't work.

I've tried:

```
$text = str_replace("\n", '', $text);
```

and

```
$text = trim($text, "\n");
```

but the output remains unchanged. Am I doing this wrong?

EDIT: Forgot to include the whole line - fixed. I *have* assigned the result back to the variable.

EDIT 2: Here is some more of my code:

```
$text = parse_bbc($row['body'], false, $row['id_msg']);
$text = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $text );
if (strlen($text) <= 300){
    echo $text . '</font></div></div>';
}else{
    $text = substr($text,0,299);
    echo $text . '</font></div></div>';
}
```

EDIT 3: I want this text:

> This is
>
> some very
>
> random
>
> dummy text

to be

> This is some very random dummy text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the html of the text you are parsing - perhaps it is an issue with `<br/>` elements or `<p></p>` hidden in the content. This would mean that the solutions may not work.

Try `trim ( $text, "\n\r\x0B")`

This will remove new lines `\n`, carriage returns `\r`, and vertical tabs `\x0B` - the main likely culprits.

Comment: why a troll downvote? If you have an issue with my answer post a comment.

Comment: eh, what now...?

Comment: not you i think @Chris - someone down voted the answer....

Comment: lol maybe this was the start :F but no haven't had that happen yet

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
$text = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $text );
```

Comment: Tried this too. Doesn't work. I'm starting to think that the problem is elsewhere...